# How to add a hover effect to increase size of text within a Vue tag?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, google-material-icons

The current code only enlarges the icon. What is the way to make it so that the text next to the icon also enlarges?

[image]

```
<style scoped>
.material-icons:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
</style>

<template>
    <div @click="folderFinder(folder)" v-for="folder in DisplayedFolders">
         <i class="material-icons">{{folder.DisplayIcon}}</i>
             {{folder.DisplayText}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply transform style in the wrapper class which contains both `icon` as well as the `text`.

**Demo :**

```css
.transform-me {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.transform-me:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div class="transform-me">
<i class="material-icons">folder</i>Hello World!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have Vue.js knowledge so not sure if this is helpful:

If you can change the markup, you could wrap `{{folder.DisplayText}}` in a `<p>` element or a `<span>` and then use `element + element` CSS selector. Something like this:

```
<style scoped>
.material-icons:hover,
.material-icons:hover + p {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
</style>

<template>
    <div @click="folderFinder(folder)" v-for="folder in DisplayedFolders">
         <i class="material-icons">{{folder.DisplayIcon}}</i>
         <p>{{folder.DisplayText}}</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

If you can't change the markup, then apply a class to the whole `<div>` container and use the `:hover` on that container.